# TFS DB backup using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tfs

TFS have more then one DB.. I want to take backup every day...

No need to over rite every day back up it want to create separate

Help me

Answer (score 1):

Open SQL Server Management Studio, connect to your TFS, open Management, right-click Maintenance Plans, select New Maintenance Plan, follow the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

In the TFS 2010 September Power Tools there is a backup plan wizard to backup your TFS server (read tfs databases) on a regular base: [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/backing-up-and-restoring-your-tfs-server/)